# Android virtual keyboard turn on caps lock

Tags: android, input, keyboard

I have an edit text field. When the user clicks on it by default it shows small letters on the virtual keyboard.

I want by default to display first letter caps and rest of them small on the keyboard.

How can this be done?

Comment: Have a look @ InputMethodManager Method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `android:capitalize="sentences"` to the definition of the `EditText` in your `Layout` file. This should `capitalize` the first character of the sentence. If you want to begin each word with a capital letter use words.

More about this can be found in the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:capitalize).

Comment: I also found that you can use android:inputType="textCapSentences"

Comment: You should use android:inputType="textCapSentences" android:capitalize is deprecated.

Answer (score 11):

**`android:capitalize`** is deprecated. So please use: **`android:inputType`**

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to captialize every character of **EditText**
use these property.

```
android:capitalize="characters"
```

Answer (score 4):

I used below attribute with `textCapCharacters` value in my `EditText` to turn on caps lock on the virtual keypad and it worked.

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

Answer (score 1):

To capitalize all characters of Keyboard use this in your `edittext` in xml:

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

To capitalize of the first character of every sentence use this :

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```