# Delphi TEdit in Android - turn off auto-caps on a per TEdit basis

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Currently, the Android TEdit when it brings up the Keyboard, will have the keyboard in Caps for first letter.

I would like to turn off Keyboard auto going into Caps for first letter.  Note: I don't want to do this in Android - Settings -> which will apply to the whole app.  I want to do it on a per TEdit basis.

Surprisingly, I couldn't find info on doing this in Delphi.  The properties in TEdit also don't seem to have anything on Capitalization.

I can't use the TEdit.CharCase feature as it forces all input in TEdit to lowercase.

What I want is that user can Type in Mixed Case if *they choose to* but the Keyboard has to be in lowercase when TEdit first comes into focus.

[Android virtual keyboard turn on caps lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847221/android-virtual-keyboard-turn-on-caps-lock)

Looking at above link, it seems that it's possible to accomplish.

How do I do this in Delphi?

Delphi 10.2 (moving to 10.4.1 soon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Delphi 10.4.1, you could do it this way, for example:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  FMX.Platform.Android;

procedure TForm1.Edit2Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PlatformAndroid.TextInputManager.GetEditText.setInputType(TJInputType.JavaClass.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
end;
```

I had 2 edit controls in my test app. The above code is the OnEnter event handler for the 2nd edit. It doesn't capitalize the first character

I expect you won't be able to use this with 10.2

Comment: I just realized IOS behaves the same way. If someone replies with the solution for IOS here, I'll amend the question to include IOS.  (if not, I'll post as a separate question)

Comment: Sadly, fixes for iOS are way more invasive, as they involve modifying the FMX source. If you post another question for it, I can answer

Comment: thanks, I have posted it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65299636/delphi-tedit-in-ios-turn-off-auto-caps-on-a-per-tedit-basis